# What major real-earth historical events had a different outcome because of Marvel Supers?

Tags: marvel, history, alternate-history

I am interested to know if any past event (let’s only consider Earth's timeline up to World War II, for the sake of brevity — the events from WWII to the present are well-covered in the comics).

We know some Marvel super-beings’ origins are rooted in Earth's past (some of them had secondary characters like sidekicks and allies I won't mention, i.e. Bucky):

1. Captain America, Nick Fury, Red Skull (and some Russian hero, I forgot the name) all fought in World War II, but the outcome was the same (axis defeated, allies victorious, Cold War, Germany split).
2. Apocalypse (En Sabah Nur) and Ozymandias were pharaohs/deities in ancient Egypt. But I don't think much has changed (Pyramids were built, library of Alexandria still burned, someone was revered as deity).
3. The Celestials seeded Earth. But pre-history was still the same.

(If I got wrong any of the above, please correct me).

Was any past event in the Marvel Universe radically different from Real Earth®™?

Comment: “let’s only consider Earth's timeline up to World War II, for the sake of brevity” — sure, just that brief period between the Second World War and the formation of the planet.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Even though it is much time, Not much happened, historically, and even less in the comic books. [90% of the world information was produced in the last 2 years](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2013/05/130522085217.htm) for example. So there are less comics covering what happened before WWII than what happened after.

Comment: particularly during the [Boring Billion](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg22229672-900-why-did-evolution-stall-during-the-boring-billion/), of course.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite do you mean **[Galactus' Naptime](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/galactus/4005-2149/)**?

Comment: If the superheroes who fought in WWII were super, they should have saved a number of lives  on their side who would have died and killed some enemies who would have lived.  After a few thousand years any person will either have no living descendants or else be the ancestor of every living person. Thus the Marvel superheroes in WWII will change the entire human population thousands of years in the future and for all the countless thousands of years that humanity survives after that.  Is that a big enough change?

Answer (score 3):

Speaking of World War II, one major difference would be that the original Human Torch killed Hitler instead of Hitler committing suicide:

[image: torch kills hitler]

He is cloned and later fights the Fantastic Four:

[image]

Comment: Why are there two human torches in that comic?

Comment: @Paul The smaller one is the original Human Torch's sidekick, Toro.

Answer (score 0):

The Spanish Inquisition, the colony at Roanoke have outcomes and causes that are different due to the existence of mutants/super heroes in the comic 'Marvel:1607'  However, this is an alternate universe, and not directly the 'main' marvel universe.

There could be some historical moments in the American Civil War that was adjusted by the presence of Wolverine, if "X-Men Origins:Wolverine" is to be believed.